# csv file manipulation in unix and append value to each line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have the below csv file

```
,,,Test File,
,todays Date:,01/10/2018,Generation date,10/01/2019 11:20:58
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
,My account no,100102GFC,,
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
TEST
```

I need to extract the todays date that is in 3rd column of the second line
and also the account number which is in 3rd column of the 4th line.

Below is the new file that i have to create, those extracted values 
from 3rd and 4th line needs to be appended at the end of the file.
New file will contain the data from the 4th line and n-1 line

```
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
```

Kindly could you please help me how to do the same in a shell script?
Here is what i tried, i am new to shell scripting, unable to combine all these

To extract the date from second row

```
sed -sn 2p test.csv| cut -d ',' -f  3
```

To extract the account no

```
sed -sn 3p test.csv| cut -d ',' -f  3
```

To extract the actual data

```
tail -n +5 test.csv | head -n -1>temp.csv
```

Comment: Please show what you have done to the moment, SE is not scripting service.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have updated the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==2{d=$3}NR==4{a=$3}NR>4{if (line) print line; line = $0 "," d "," a;}' Inputfile.csv
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file1
,,,Test File,
,todays Date:,01/10/2018,Generation date,10/01/2019 11:20:58
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
,My account no,100102GFC,,
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
TEST

$ awk -F, 'NR==2{d=$3}NR==4{a=$3}NR>4{if (line) print line; line = $0 "," d "," a;}' file1
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
```

Misunderstood your meaning before I edit your question, updated my answer afterwards.

In the `awk` command:
`NR` means the line number, `-F` to assign separator, `d` store date `a` account.
 just concatenate the line `$0` with `d` and `a`.
You don't want last line, so I used `line` to delay print, last line won't print out (though it did saved to `line`, and can be used if a `END` block is given).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat  dawn.txt
,,,Test File,
,todays Date:,01/10/2018,Generation date,10/01/2019 11:20:58
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
,My account no,100102GFC,,
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
TEST

$ perl -F, -lane ' $dt=$F[2] if $.==2 ; $ac=$F[2] if $.==4; if($.>4 and ! eof) { print "$_,$dt,$ac" } ' dawn.txt
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC

$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 2 { date = $3 }
NR == 4 { acct = $3 }
NR>4 && NF>1 { print $0, date, acct }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
```

or, depending on your requirements and actual input data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 2 { date = $3 }
NR == 4 { acct = $3 }
NR>4 {
    if (out != "") {
        print out
    }
    out = $0 OFS date OFS acct
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
A,B,C,D,E,01/10/2018,100102GFC
```